# Is there a way to dynamically create XSL file based on XSD file

Tags: xslt

I have a project where I need to convert a XML file to CSV file and vice versa. I can't use a single XSL file because, there are different XML and CSV formats. So, I am just wondering if there is any way (any tool or editors or any APIs) to create XSL file based on XSD file.

I am also open to any other suggestions too (I believe I can't avoid XSL because in the future I might be asked to convert to different formats such as pdf, html etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An XSD file describes the structure of a valid XML file that conforms to certain rules.  An XSLT file describes how to transform an input XML document to some output form, which may or may not be XML.  It is not possible to deduce an XSL transformation from an XSD file as they address completely different aspects of XML.

In other words, an XSD allows you to confirm that an XML document adheres to a predefined set of constraints, but says nothing about what to do with the XML, or how to transform it to something else.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!! Can you please advise on how exactly the XSL file is created (Is it created manually or is there any tool or editor or api for that).

Comment: XSL is usually created manually.  It is a set of templates that match elements in your xml, and the content of the templates defines the output.  You should look at the [Wikipedia entry for XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) and Google for more information.

Comment: xsd describe an xml schema which is a valid entry for an xslt transformation.

Answer (score 5):

I realise that this was asked and answered a good 3 years ago, but I came across it while asking myself the same question. The short answer is yes, of course, because you are simply converting one type of XML to another (albeit with some structural and syntax changes). I saw this: https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200807/msg00601.html - which outlines a basic implementation as proof of concept, and I used that as a starting point to create the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" /> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:comment> ............................................................................................... </xsl:comment>

        <xsl:element name="xsl:stylesheet">
            <xsl:namespace name="xsl" select="'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'" /> <xsl:attribute name="version" select="'1.0'" /> 

            <xsl:element name="xsl:output">
                <xsl:attribute name="indent" select="'yes'" />
                <xsl:attribute name="method" select="'xml'" />
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:comment> ............................................................................................... </xsl:comment>
            <xsl:comment>                                                                                                 </xsl:comment>
            <xsl:comment> ............................................................................................... </xsl:comment>

            <xsl:element name="xsl:template">
                <xsl:attribute name="match" select="'/'" />
                <xsl:element name="xsl:apply-templates">
                    <xsl:attribute name="select" select="'node()'" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:comment> ............................................................................................... </xsl:comment>

            <xsl:element name="xsl:template">
                <xsl:attribute name="match" select="'node()'" />
                <xsl:element name="xsl:if">
                    <xsl:attribute name="test" select="'.!=&apos;&apos;'" />
                    <xsl:element name="xsl:copy"></xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>

            <xsl:comment> ............................................................................................... </xsl:comment>
            <xsl:comment>                                                                                                 </xsl:comment>
            <xsl:comment> ............................................................................................... </xsl:comment>

            <xsl:apply-templates /> 
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:comment> ............................................................................................... </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:complexType[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="xsl:template">
            <xsl:attribute name="match" select="@name" />
            <xsl:apply-templates /> 
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:comment> ............................................................................................... </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:complexType[not(@*)]">
        <xsl:element name="xsl:apply-templates">
            <xsl:attribute name="select" select="@name" />
            <xsl:apply-templates /> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- xsl:template match="xs:simpleType[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="xsl:apply-templates">
            <xsl:attribute name="select" select="@name" />
            <xsl:apply-templates /> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template -->

    <xsl:template match="xs:sequence">
        <xsl:element name="xsl:copy">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:element[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="xsl:apply-templates">
            <xsl:attribute name="select" select="@name" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:attribute">
        <xsl:element name="xsl:apply-templates">
            <xsl:attribute name="select" select="concat( '@', @name )" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- xsl:template match="xs:element[@name]">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:element name="xsl:template">
            <xsl:attribute name="match" select="@name" /> 
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:comment>
                auto generated stub for element <xsl:value-of select="@name" /> 
            </xsl:comment>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates /> 
    </xsl:template -->

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of `xsl:element` to create the XSLT tags and creating `select` and `match` attributes, the quoting in selects and escaping. The `comment` blocks are there to visually break up the root of the document (make it more readable) but serve no other purpose. Also, this requires an XSLT 2.0 processor. `xsltproc` users need not apply.

As per the previous responses, you'll have to modify it in varying degrees for your use case. I made this so that I could quickly create an accurate skeleton from which I could build out a useful XSLT document, while automating the tedious groundwork.

Naturally, I've just spent hours developing and testing something that at this point I probably could have done faster by hand with grep, but at least it was interesting. Hope this helps someone and improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the assertion in your question, you **can** actually use a single XSLT file to convert from generic CSV to XML. Refer: [Kernow's converter](http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like Jim Garrison said, there are no simple mapping between XSD and XSLT. But they are both XML formats, so it is not impossible to map one to the other. Depending on the general structure of the formats, it could also be possible to write a generic XSLT to map any XML directly to CSV, if the structure is simple enough.

You will have to provide some examples of the XML data, the XSD and expected result.

Comment: Yes, I accept. I am done with the XSL file and it is doing the transformation perfectly. Thanks for your interest!!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is - YES. It can be done. If you look at Eclipse there is a function which generates sample XML based on XSD. So it will be possible to make own XSTL transformation for XSD to obtain another XSLT - but this time based on source XSD. I won't be easy but it is achievable.