# Readymade XSLT for XSD

Tags: xslt, xsd

Since `XSD` is always specific except the element names, can there a ready made `XSLT` available to convert it to a `HTML`?

We may have a requirement, where, user can provide specifications for the job inputs in `XSD`, which is shown as `HTML` in `GUI`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want to display an HTML rendition of the schema, or an HTML rendition of an instance XML document that conforms to the schema?

Answer (score 0):

An XSD file describes the structure of a valid XML file that conforms to certain rules. An XSLT file describes how to transform an input XML document to some output form, which may or may not be XML. It is not possible to deduce an XSL transformation from an XSD file as they address completely different aspects of XML. please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254066/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-create-xsl-file-based-on-xsd-file])